# Should I close MongoDB connection after that lambda function executes the code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda

I have a **lambda** function that runs inside a **Step Function *Map State***. In this lambda I have a ***db.connect()*** function that opens a new connection (since lambda executed inside a loop, it will create multiple connections). The question is, should I close the MongoDB connection after that lambda executes the code? If I don't close the connection, will it stay open? If so, will MongoDB server try to close the connection after a while? What's the best practice for this situation? Thanks!

**λ**

```
export const handler = async (_, context) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false

  try {
    const dbConn = await db.connect()
    ...
  } finally {
    await db.disconnect() // is this necessary?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation outlined here [[1](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/manage-connections-aws-lambda/#manage-connections-with-aws-lambda)]:
If you create your client outside the function and reuse it this would be a better practice. Potentially the connection would close itself after the defined timeout. So I don't think you need to explicitly close out the connection.